# Pythonanywere не работают Api

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

У меня есть бэкэнд часть с API, которые должны работать, но когда я захожу на web и отправляю какие либо запросы, они отправляются и выдает статус 200, но при этом ничего в базе данных не меняется. Но если я сделаю тоже самое через админку или swager то все работает, ктому же мои API как то не так выглядят помогите пожалуйста
[image: Вот так выглядят настройки моего web] [image: Вторая картинка][image: Вот так выглядит моя апи] [image: А вот так админка]

Вот так выглядит сама API и модели к ней

```
class StudentRegisterView(APIView):
permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

@swagger_auto_schema(
    request_body=openapi.Schema(
        type=openapi.TYPE_OBJECT,
        required=['email', 'password', 'name', 'second_name'],
        properties={
            'email': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING),
            'password': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING),
            'password2': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING),
            'name': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING),
            'second_name': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING),
        },
    ),
    responses={200: 'OK', 400: 'Invalid Data'},
    operation_description="Register a new student"
)

def post(self, request):
    serializer = TheUserSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        theuser = TheUser.objects.create(
            email=request.data['email'],
            name=request.data['name'],
            second_name=request.data['second_name'],
        )
        theuser.set_password(request.data['password'])
        theuser.save()
        StudentProfile.objects.create(studentuser=theuser)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)




class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    is_Teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.email}'


class TheUser(MyUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
    second_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
```

Comment: Было бы не плохо, если бы вы предоставили код. На текущий момент, я могу лишь сказать, что скорее всего эта ошибка связана с тем, что вы в коде api перехвата post запроса либо не создаете объект связанной модели, либо не используете метод save().